# Lane Detection in an artificial Environment

Tags: computer-vision, hough-transform

I'm writing an app that can detect lanes in a driving simulator. The environment is relatively simple, its mostly straight multi-lane roads and almost no curvature at all. At the moment, I can successfully detect lines using the (classical) Hough Transform but the issue is that the HT naturally also detects lines that are not lanes.

How can I be more selective? I do not draw horizontal lines already, but still some lines creep in. Ideally, I would like to detect the lane boundaries that the vehicle is traveling in. The following is a typical image of the environment

[image: Environment]

Here is what I'm doing so far:

  1. Because the environment is more or less the same wherever I drive, I set the region of interest (RoI) to exclude the horizon and anything above it.

  2. Threshold the image (I'll explain my reason for threshold in a bit)

  3. Canny Edge Detection

  4. Apply a Hough Transform

  5. Draw the detected lines excluding those which have a gradient of 0.0 or nearly 0.0

The reason for threshold the imaging is as follows. If you take a look at the environment photograph linked above, you'll see a grayish line running parallel to the road. Because its a continuous line - unlike the lane markers - the HT ends up detecting it. I cannot exclude it based on gradient as it has the same gradient as the lane markers. With thresholding, i can remove that and therefore only detect lines that are the actual lane markers.

Here is the result of the above operations

[image: Hough Transform]

I understand that there are many solutions to this problem and I have read countless papers on this but they all seem to be handling environments vastly more complicated than this and/or are simply way over my head. For what its worth, just a little more than a month ago, I had no background in ComputerVision and so all of this is very very new to me.

**UPDATE 1:**

I guess to put this in better terms, I'm looking for a way to model the lanes so that lines that do not fit the model are not included. Unfortunately, I do not have a clue about where to begin with models. Any suggestions?

For what its worth, I have managed to identify the lanes that the vehicle is traveling within and can exclude the extra lines that are not part of the "active" lane, so to speak. Hopefully this photo will help

[image: Screenshot]

Its not perfect, but its something I guess. My ultimate goal, after modeling, is to generate a heading/position of the vehicle. But I just want to get, relatively, robust lane detection at first. I'm hoping there is a *relatively* simple technique that can help achieve this (something that does not depend on the system's parameters such as focal length of field of view).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go would be to use prior knowledge of the scene you are looking at. You could have a model with a hidden state, comprising more or less static parameters such as camera height, camera tilt or lane width, and dynamic parameters such as camera yaw, lateral displacement of the camera within the lane, road curvature, etc. You could handle such model in the frame of a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter). An advantage of such a model would be an ability to tolerate other road surface markings such as direction arrows, zebras and such. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find out the camera height and other parameters from the driving simulator. However, the environment looks exactly like the photo above 95% of the time. Would the said method still be worthwhile to investigate?

Comment: If you know the field of view of the camera, you can determine the tilt from the vanishing point y coordinate. If you know the tilt (pitch) and the lane width you can determine the camera height.

Comment: Is there a way I can find the field of view empirically? Without knowing the focal length. The issue is that the driving sim was not programmed by me and is infact from another company entirely. While I will try and ask them about such things, I do not think that answering such questions would be high on their priority list!

Comment: i dont think the height needs to be exact. if you're approx. ±6" (15cm) within the actual value, you should be within a 5% margin of error on calculating lane width using this method.

Comment: Any other techniques that you could suggest? What about something based on splines/active contours - something that would not require parameters? I say this because I read up on Kalman filters for quite some time and I'm just unable to understand them. Sorry to be so thick :(

Comment: It's hard to propose a solution when we do not know what are your problems. Bring us a case study which shows why are you unsatisfied with the method you presently use.

Comment: I am not using any lane detection system at the present. I'm trying to implement one in the above mentioned environment. Since the environment is relatively simple, I was hoping I could use a simple/easy to understand technique which I could then implement and then progress further from there. The basic requirement is that it should be able to handle gentle curves and straight lanes and maybe deduce the heading of the vehicle. As said before, I know very little about the environment that I'm working on and so cannot find the parameters such as the focal length and field of view of the camera.

Comment: @ssegvic Hi, could you please shed more light onto how to define and use the model? I am currently trying to detect lanes in a video in real environment.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try to find only lines on edges found at grey-white transitions rather than on all edges in the entire image?

Comment: Here's what I've come up with. Not sure how elegant it is. I'm going to setup a wide (but short in height) region of interest (RoI) in the image. Its going to be located about 3/5th the way down. If and only if a line intersects the bottom of this RoI, I will draw it. If you take a look at this picture: http://tinyurl.com/349hscq (the selection=RoI) you'll see that only the lane boundaries that the vehicle is traveling within will intersect the bottom of the selection and hence I can mark them as "lanes" and draw them accordingly. I know it won't work in all cases but I wanted to run it here.

Comment: sounds reasonable. In practical computer-vision, whatever works works. Save computer-scientific or statistical clarity or accuracy for when you have something that does anything.